# How I use button to delete an array of checkboxes in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a form that display the uid,names and major and checkboxes to select which will be deleted. The form has delete button and when we press on it is shows another button to confirm.
After pressing confirm it must send the array of checkboxes to another php and use isset($confirm) to delete them from the query.

```
if (isset($Confirm)) {
    foreach ($_POST['chbox'] as $val) {
        $sql = "Delete from studentsdb where uid=$val";

        header("Location:RemoveStudents.php");
    }
}

$r = $db->exec($sql);
$db = null;
```

Its only delete the last record in the array, so where is the problem?
**Note= The question must not use javascript**

Comment: Think about your flow. In your loop, you set the sql, then call header, set sql again, and call header again. This happens over and over until the loop exits. After loop exit, the sql statement has the very last id from the loop when `exec` gets called. So, you ultimately only run one query, with whatever the last id may be. The exec should move inside the loop after the sql. Move the `header` to a point just after the loop. No need to do: `$db = null;`. Side note: you are wide open to sql injection! Learn to use prepared queries as soon as you can.